# Using a loop to describe multiple conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

In the following code, I am trying to extract numbers from a list in which all digits are divisible by 2. The following code works.

```
l = range(100,401)
n=[]
for i in l:
    s =str(i)
    if all([int(s[0])%2==0,int(s[1])%2==0,int(s[2])%2==0]):
          n.append(s)
    print(",".join(n))
```

I was trying to insert a for loop to avoid writing all three conditions explicitly.

```
l = range(100,401)
n=[]
ss=[]
for i in l:
    s =str(i)
ss.append(s)
for element in ss:
    for j in range(3):
        if int(element[j])%2==0:
            n.append(element)

print(n)
```

I can't get the desired output. Not only that, the elements of output list 'n' at even index are printed twice. I am unable to figure out WHY?

Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't `ss.append(s)` be inside the `for`?

Comment: Yes. I am sorry it's a typo.

Comment: Hi everyone.All of the answers suggest modifications however I was more interested in knowing the flaw of the code I have written. As in, I want to know ' What is wrong in there?'.

Comment: You add `element` to the list (`n.append(element)`) up to 3 times - once for _each_  even digit. You need to change it to only add to `n` after all digits have been checked.

Comment: Got it. Thanks @JohnnyMopp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
l = range(100, 401)
n = []
for i in l:
    v = 0
    for j in str(i):
        if int(j) % 2 == 0:
            v += 1
    if v == len(str(i)):
        n.append(str(i))
print(",".join(n))
```

Or with some list comprehension:

```
l = range(100, 401)
n = []
for i in l:
    if all(int(j) % 2 == 0 for j in str(i)):
        n.append(str(i))
print(",".join(n))
```

Or with even more list comprehension:

```
l = range(100, 401)
n = [str(i) for i in l if all(int(j) % 2 == 0 for j in str(i))]
print(",".join(n))
```

Or with a ridiculous minimizing:

```
print(",".join([str(i) for i in range(100, 401) if all(int(j) % 2 == 0 for j in str(i))]))
```

#### Explaining

OP asked me to explain why his code doesn't work. I'll make it in some steps, also optimizing it:

```
l = range(100,401)
n = []
ss = []
for i in l: # You don't need this loop, you are just making a new list with string values instead of integers. You could make that on the fly.
    s = str(i)
    ss.append(s)
for element in ss:
    for j in range(3):
        if int(element[j]) % 2 == 0: # This only check if the current digit is pair and it append the whole number to the list. You have to check if the 3 numbers are pair AND then append it. 
            n.append(element)
print(n)
```

Your code check each digit and if that is true, the number is appended to the result list (`n`). But you don't want that, you want to check if the 3 digits that make the number are pair, so you have to check the whole group.

For example you could do this:

```
for element in l:
    pairs = 0
    for j in range(3):
        if int(str(element)[j]) % 2 == 0:
            pairs += 1 # Each time a digit of the number is pair, `pairs` variable increase in one
    if pairs == 3: # If the 3 digits are true it append your number
            n.append(str(element))
```

That is my first idea of how to improve your code, but instead of `element` and `pairs` I use `j` and `v`, (also I don't use `range(3)`, I just iterate over the stringed number).

If you are looking for something "better" you could try to use a list comprehension like `all(int(j) % 2 == 0 for j in str(i))`. That iterate over all the digits to check if the are pair, if all the checks are true (like 222, or 284) it returns `true`.

Let me know if I should explain something more.

Comment: Hi Ender, The loop I applied is just another form of what is done in list comprehension method. Could you please explain why the code I wrote doesn't work? Thanks

Comment: @Tapasya.A, Ok. I this moment I am busy but later I will add an explaining.

Comment: @Tapasya.A, I have just edited my post. Let me know if you understood it

Comment: Hi Ender. Thanks a lot for your effort and time.I clearly understood my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Generator expression checking if `all()` elements evaluate to `True` comes to your rescue:

```
l = range(100,401)
n=[]
for i in l:
    s = str(i)
    if all(int(ch) % 2 == 0 for ch in s):
          n.append(s)
    print(",".join(n))
```

Now it also works even if you work with more digits.

Thanks for @jpp's advice on generator expression!

---

And here a **faster** alternative where you evaluate if `any()` is not divisable with 2.

```
l = range(100,401)
n=[]
for i in l:
    s = str(i)
    if any(int(ch) % 2 != 0 for ch in s):
        continue
    else:
        n.append(s)
    print(",".join(n))
```

Comment: I added a quicker alternative with `any()`. As any needs just one true to evaluate to true it will find "non-accepted" values faster.

Answer (score 1):

Try this method. You don't need to check all the numbers.
You just need to change the range statement from `range(100, 401)` to `range (100, 401, 2)` and add some checks as the Numbers which have first digit as Odd you can skip all the 100 numbers and then in next 10 series you can skip 10 if the tenth digit is odd. It reduces the complexity and decreases your processing time.

```
l = range(100, 401, 2)
n = []
for i in l:
    s = str(i)
    if int(s[0]) % 2 == 1:
        remainder = i % 100
        i = i - remainder + 100 - 1
        continue
    elif int(s[1])%2 == 1:
        remainder = i % 10
        i = i - remainder + 10 - 1
        continue
    n.append(s)
print(",".join(n))
```